# The type 'SecurityTokenDescriptor' exists in both 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, Version=5.6.0.0' and 'Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.'

Tags: c#, .net-core

I can't seem to find a way to resolve this issue, it just wont compile. Please advise of any info I can provide to make my question clearer.

Here is the class that is generating the conflict - the error appears under `new SecurityTokenDescriptor`:

```
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DatingApp.API.Data;
using DatingApp.API.Dtos;
using DatingApp.API.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace DatingApp.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]

    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IAuthRepository _repo;
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public AuthController(IAuthRepository repo, IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
            _repo = repo;
        }


        [HttpPost("register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(UserForRegisterDto userForRegisterDto)
        {
            userForRegisterDto.Username = userForRegisterDto.Username.ToLower();

            if (await _repo.UserExists(userForRegisterDto.Username))
                return BadRequest("Username already exists");

            var userToCreate = new User
            {
                Username = userForRegisterDto.Username
            };

            var createdUser = await _repo.Register(userToCreate, userForRegisterDto.Password);

            return StatusCode(201);
        }

        [HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> login(UserForLoginDto userForLoginDto)
        {


            var userFromRepo = await _repo.Login(userForLoginDto.Username.
                ToLower(), userForLoginDto.Password);

            if (userFromRepo == null)
                return Unauthorized();

            var claims = new[]
            {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userFromRepo.Id.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userFromRepo.Username)
            };

            var key = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8
            .GetBytes(_config.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value));

            var creds = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                SigningCredentials = creds

            };

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

            return Ok(new {
                token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token)
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you dont need Microsoft.IdentityModel in this class. Therefor you can fix the conflict by removing Microsoft.IdentityModel from the package referencing list.

Goto : [projectname].csproj

**Remove this**

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel" Version="6.0.0"/>`

**and build the project.**

if you need identity model again, add that reference and build the project.

Answer (score 0):

Specify which namespace you want it to use

```
var tokenDescriptor = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
    SigningCredentials = creds
};
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I have tried that and the error remains.

Comment: OK. You aren't referencing `Microsoft.IdentityModel` in this file - do you need both packages in your project?